# Validation matcher for xml sequence elements in Citrus

Tags: java, xml, integration-testing, citrus-framework

I have a question regarding the correct usage of the Citrus validation matchers. In the official XML example there is the following XSD schema ([TodoList.xsd](https://github.com/christophd/citrus-samples/blob/master/sample-soap/src/test/resources/schema/TodoList.xsd)) defined for a `getTodoListResponse`:

```
<xs:element name="getTodoListResponse">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="list">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="todoEntry" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="id" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element name="description" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <xs:element name="attachment" minOccurs="0">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element name="cid" type="xs:string"/>
                          <xs:element name="contentType" type="xs:string"/>
                          <xs:element name="data" type="xs:string"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="done" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

The validation matcher that is defined looks like this ([templates/getTodoListResponse.xml](https://github.com/christophd/citrus-samples/blob/master/sample-soap/src/test/resources/templates/getTodoListResponse.xml)):

```
<todo:getTodoListResponse xmlns:todo="http://citrusframework.org/samples/todolist">
  <todo:list>
    <todo:todoEntry>
      <todo:id>@ignore@</todo:id>
      <todo:title>${todoName}</todo:title>
      <todo:description>${todoDescription}</todo:description>
    </todo:todoEntry>
  </todo:list>
</todo:getTodoListResponse>
```

But when running the test multiple times via `mvn verify` there are multiple todoEntry elements in the resulting XML. In order to check this variable list of XML elements that come back in the result. Therefore the check will fail.

The question is, if there is a way to express this dynamic list via the XML validation matcher API.

I got a working solution which is based on the groovy validator like this:
`assert root.list.children().size() > 1` ([getTodoListResponseValidator.groovy](https://github.com/mariodavid/cucumber-citrus-spring-soap-example/blob/master/src/test/resources/templates/getTodoListResponseValidator.groovy))

But I would rather like to see this working through the XML validation. It seems there is something similar called [@matchesXml()](https://www.citrusframework.org/reference/html/#matcher-matches-xml), but from the docs it is not clear for me if this is suitable for the described use case.

Thx in advance.

Bye
Mario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bottom line this is just a bad designed test for the todo-list demo. Integration tests should always operate on a well-known state of the application under test. And the tests should always leave a clean state for other tests to come. These principles are violated in that particular sample.

In fact the sample that you mention is just a demo and therefore not written as a full qualified real world example. Following from that the tests are not working when executed multiple times.

To fix this I would recommend to clear the todo list in a before-test step so you always operate on an empty list. Another possibility would be to use XPath validation instead of comparing the complete list of entries. The XPath validation can check the amount of list entries to be greater that zero for instance (just like you did in the groovy script).

In addition to that you could write a XPath expression that only validates the last entry in that list of todos returned by the server. Something like that

```
<validate path="count(//todo:todoEntry)" value="@greaterThan(0)@" result-type="number"/>
<validate path="//todo:todoEntry[last()]/todo:title" value="${todoName}"></validate>
```

Comment: i did not want to criticize your example. It is just an example for the problem that I have. I get back dynamic list of entries where the order is not clear (as well as the number of elements). Is it possible to ignore complete subparts of the request (like: `<todoList>@ignore@</todoList>`) and make other checks (like you mentioned) for the subpart additionally?

Comment: no problem, I just wanted to clarify the demo nature. Yes, you can ignore the todolist subelement in XML compare and additionally add XPath validations.